# Чем отличается колбэк от слушателя?

Tags: java, callback, интерфейс, listener

Например, чтобы обработать нажатие на `Button` необходимо воспользоваться методом `setOnClickListener` передав оному `OnClickListener` (слушатель). И такой `Listener` много где встречается.

А вот, у Google Maps, например, есть метод `getMapAsync`, в который надо передать `OnMapReadyCallback`.

Чем отличается **Listener** от **Callback**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Слушатель, по сути, это и есть `callback`.

Я не буду объяснять, для чего нужны коллбэки, почему их используют в асинхронном программировании, и всё такое прочее.

Но вы видимо не совсем поняли: слушатель это просто обычный коллбэк, вы передаете его какому-то обработчику, этот коллбэк там где-то регистрируется и в последствии может быть неоднократно вызван.

Тот же пример, который вы привели - `OnClickListener` - это обычный интерфейс, и в случае нажатия пользователем на ваш элемент, будет вызван определенный метод.

Где-то происходит "прослушка" событий, и, как только событие произошло, оно будет "услышано". На разные события есть свои "слушатели", которые на них реагируют. И, в случае если коллбэк (слушатель) передан и событие произошло, будет вызван нужный метод - например, тот же `onClick` у слушателя нажатий, и вы сможете это событие обработать.

Comment: спасибо, понял)

Answer (score 5):

Принципиально ничем. Единственное заметное отличие в том, что обычно есть возможность зарегистрировать множество слушателей, но функцию обратного вызова можно использовать только одну.

Answer (score 5):

Listener принято называть интерфейсы обратного вызова, ответственные за реакцию на действия, как нажатия кнопки.

Callback - интерфейсы обратного вызова, ответственные за реакцию на события, как завершение получения данных.

Стоит заметить, что разделение это весьма условно и вполне может не соблюдаться какими то разработчиками.

По сути реализации это один и тот же механизм интерфейса обратного вызова и в этом плане у них отличий нет.